# How do I validate if a ANSI SQL has Syntax errors or a DDL sentence?

Tags: sql, validation, ddl, ansi-sql

I want to know both things without executing the code.

Is there a way to do this without coding a half-to-be-compiler?

I would be passing an sql to a process or something which validates this stuff before I send it to execute...

---

**@EDIT** : Answers to the comment questions:

*What are you trying to validate?*

- ANSI SQL Syntax, and to know whether they are or aren't using DDL sentences.

*Is this user input, if so, how are they inputting the SQL statement?*

- They write a *.sql file. I just recieve it without knowing where (in what IDE) did they write it and I have to validate the ANSI syntax (not the semantics)

*Is this from code? How are you executing the code?*

- I shouldn't have to execute it. An Operations employee would do that. When it's needed to. If you mean *the code* as to the ANSISyntaxAndDDLCheckerSomething that I'm looking for, I would run it with a console App... probably with.Net

Comment: What are you trying to validate? Is this user input, if so, how are they inputting the SQL statement? Is this from code? How are you executing the code?

Answer (score 1):

Realistically, there isn't anything much short of a full SQL analyzer (such as those found inside a DBMS) that can validate the SQL.  This is doubly true since what is valid according to the SQL standard is not necessarily valid according to your target DBMS.  The grammar for the [SQL standard](http://savage.net.au/SQL) is big and complex.  There are lots of constraints on what is allowed that are not prescribed by the [BNF](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus_Naur_Form) that describes the main syntax of the language.

The semantic checks are very complex too.  For example, a statement such as:

```
SELECT * FROM SomeTable;
```

is syntactically correct (and you can see that, and I can see that), but there's no way of knowing whether it will execute successfully against a given database.  It depends on whether there is a table called `SomeTable` in the database at the time when the query is executed.  Add explicit column names, and you have to check that the column names are valid at the time when the query is executed too.  You could have a syntactically valid CREATE TABLE statement that will fail to execute because there's a view with the same name as the table already in existence.

If you prepare a statement without executing it, you get a syntax and semantic check on the statement.  It is likely the most reliable way of finding out what you're after.

Comment: I'm not looking for semantic checking. Just Syntax and DDL... you can never expect to validate semantics without a compiler. But maybe a Syntax check, or a specific format check and/or if are there or not (a boolean definition) DDL on the queries, just maybe, is something that can do it without the compiler.

Comment: I mean IDK, but maybe sqlparser.com has something like the stuff I'm looking for, but I'm not sure if I'm on the right track.

Comment: If a server supports the creation of a database with MODE ANSI, would ANSI/ISO SQL statements be compatible with that database?

Comment: @FrankComputer: An Informix style 'MODE ANSI' database accepts both standard and non-standard SQL statements. There is an option `-ansi` that can be used to generate warnings for non-ANSI statements (or statement where components of the statement are not ANSI).  But that's all peculiar to Informix.

Comment: An alternative, although limited, for achieving SQL statement DB independence would be to use [HQL](http://www.hibernate.org/).